# Update Node JS on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Version 14.0.0 is installed, node -v always shows it. Although in the list of programs Node appears as 16.13.1. I can manually change the version via nvm, but this is very inconvenient. How to make sure that there is no ghost on my computer about version 14?

Answer (score 5):

You can use n module from npm in order to upgrade node

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

to update to the latest version use

```
sudo n latest
```

[Explained](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version)

Comment: `antonz@comp:~$ node -v`
`v14.0.0`
`antonz@comp:~$ sudo npm cache clean -f`
`[sudo] password for antonz: `
`npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.`
`antonz@comp:~$ sudo npm install -g n`

`added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 2s`

`found 0 vulnerabilities`
`antonz@comp:~$ sudo n stable`
   `installed : v16.13.1 (with npm 8.1.2)`
`antonz@comp:~$ node -v`
`v14.0.0`

Comment: 14.0.0 again..(((

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem

```
rm -rf ~/.nvm
nvm install 16
```